# Show that $|X|=|X^G|$ (mod p)

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a p-group, that is ,$|G|=p^n$ where $p$ is a prime and $n$ is a positive integer. Suppose that $G$ acts on a set $X$. Show that $|X|=|X^G|$ (mod p). $X^G=\{x\in{X}|gx=x \forall{g\in{G}}\}$.

I don't really have idea for this question, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $X=\mathcal{O}(x_1)\cup \mathcal{O}(x_2)\cup \cdots \cup \mathcal{O}(x_r)$, disjoint union of all orbits, and $X^G$ is union of singleton orbits.

Hence $|X|$ is the totality of all orbit-sizes whereas $|X^G|$ is the totality of the singleton orbit-sizes. Thus, the quantity $|X|-|X^G|$ is the totality of those orbit-sizes where orbits are *not singleton*.

If an orbit is not singleton, then is its cardinality divisible by $p$?